# How to disable the system beep of LMDE?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, kernel-modules, bell

I got annoyed with the system beep of Linux Mint Debian Edition when I login or logout. I have found some solutions like:

```
echo "blacklist pcspkr" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

but it didn't work for me. How can I turn off the beep?

Comment: You may need to blacklist `snd_pcsp` as well...

Comment: I tried to add blacklist `snd_pcsp`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: For that to work, your speaker driver has to be built as a module; here I disable it with `modprobe.blacklist=pcspkr` in the kernel boot parameters. First, do `lsmod | grep pcspkr` and check if it returns anything. If it doesn't, then it's not built as a module; if it does and blacklisting does remove it from the list, then maybe the beep is not made through the system speaker?

Comment: And I think `snd_pcsp` is a completely different thing, you want to blacklist `pcspkr`, which is what provides you the usual beep speaker; I think `snd_pcsp` is a driver to use that speaker as you would use external speakers (play mp3s, etc); if I am correct, disabling it won't disable the usual beep at all, because it's a separate driver.

Comment: Yes, I don't find any driver about `snd_pcsp`.By the way, how to disable `modprobe.blacklist=pcspkr` in the kernel boot?

Comment: From all the tutorials I've found, this is the only one that worked for me: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1116

Answer (score 5):

Well, the easiest is to set `setterm -blength`, It'll set the beep length to 0.

when it's about X, then I'd advice `xset b off`, it'll disable the beep in X.

Comment: The `setterm -blength` turn off the terminal beep, not the system beep.

Comment: And I often login by mdm.